# python: why doesn't this code work?

Tags: python

stMa[][] is an ndarray(a 7823*12 matrix), and its values'type is numpy.float64.
My original code is:

```
x=[]
for i in range(0,7823):
    if stMa[i][6] == 100:
        x.append(i)
print(x)
```

But the output is:

```
[]
[Finished in 9.0s]
```

It is very strange because I am sure that there must be some items having value of 100 in the seventh column.
When I modify this code to check the stMa[i][6]:

```
x=[]
for i in range(0,7823):
    if stMa[i][6] == 100:
        x.append(i)
    print(stMa[i][6]) 
print(x)
```

Now, part of the output is:

```
51.3672727273
100.0
100.0
77.8559585492
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
22.9720207254
[]
[Finished in 9.5s]
```

So there are definitely some items of value 100 in stMa[i][6]. Then, why is the list "x" null?

**New question:**
Why Python can find items of value"0" in stMa[i][6] when I use

```
if stMa[i][6] == 0:
```

Comment: What’s the type of `stMa[i][6]`? `print(repr(stMa[i][6]))`

Comment: What is `stMa`? Please try to make a [mcve]

Comment: <class 'numpy.float64'>

Comment: Comparing floating point values in Python for equality is ... a PITA. In your case you could write ``if int(stMa[i][6]) == 100:`` (what prints as ``100.0`` *might* actually be ``100.0000000001``)

Comment: stMa is an ndarray(a 7823*12 matrix)

Comment: @mpf82: it will be better to check if `abs(float_value - other_float_value) < sys.float_info.epsilon`, but in this case it will be overkill i guess

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: That check doesn’t make any sense. For small values, it’s inaccurate, and for larger values, it’s the same as `==`.

Comment: @mpf82 It works! But now I have another question that why Python can find the items of value "0" when I just use <pre>if stMa[i][6] == 0<code>?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is likely because you're trying to check if two floating point numbers are exactly equal - which is a dangerous game.

Try using the numpy `isclose` method instead:

```
x=[]
for i in range(0,7823):
    if np.isclose(stMa[i][6], 100):
        x.append(i)
print(x)
```

Or, use numpy's `where` function to do this without the loop:

```
x = np.where(np.isclose(stMa[:][6], 100))
```

Comment: When I check the matrix (or a table) in Excel, I can find there are 685 items of value "100". However, if I use "np.isclose(stMa[i][6], 100)", it tells the number of the wanted items is 690. So it is a little inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your stMa[i][6] is not str
or probably you can change the code to`

`x=[]
for i in range(0,7823):
    if float(stMa[i][6]) == 100.0:
        x.append(i)
print(x)`

Comment: Then just change it to float, or you can even use  str(stMa[i][6]) == str(100.0)

Comment: " int(stMa[i][6]) == 100 " can work, but " float(stMa[i][6]) == 100.0 " cannot find the wanted items.

Comment: then try using str(stMa[i][6]) == str(100.0)